# How do I replace a GFCI breaker with a normal breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

I have a breaker on my panel that has 2 white wires and one black and a test button. I am changing to a breaker that has no white wires going to it just the black. Do I put both white wires to the bar or only the bigger one?

Comment: Why are there two white wires?  Is the original breaker a 2-pole breaker?

Comment: Where does each white wire go? I'm guessing one goes to the neutral bar and could be completely removed from the panel. Assuming you have a GFCI breaker, are you within code to remove it?

Comment: The breaker has a small white wire and a larger white wire going to the breaker. Only the black wire has a screw the whites go in the breaker so i would have to cut those

Comment: It has a test button on it and two white one black. the black is the only one with a screw

Comment: it's a 15 amp breaker that keeps triping.The guy at Lowes said to change it out with this one. Says it will work with out triping like the breaker with the test button.

Comment: You can almost never replace A GFCI or AFCI breaker with a normal circuit breaker, it's almost surely a code violation. Lowe's employees are not Electricians,  nor are they electrical inspectors.  Contact your local building department before proceeding.

Comment: Hey! It might tripping because it's preventing your house from burning down!

Comment: After reading all the comments this is a washing machine circuit, that a newer washer trips the gfci on the spin cycle , I would bet that the washer uses a variable frequency drive and that is what is tripping the GFCI. Gfci's don't do well with motor loads especially VFD's because of the harmonics generated. My state allows dedicated circuits like this to use standard breakers because of the known problems.

Answer (score 5):

First, it sounds like the old breaker is a GFCI or AFCI, and the new one is not. Changing types like that is likely a code violation and can compromise the safety of your electrical system. Do not do this unless you know why a GFCI or AFCI breaker was installed and that you have removed the conditions from that branch circuit that required their installation.

Second, since you are asking this type of question, you likely don't have the experience to do this safely. At this point, I recommend you hire an electrician.

If you insist on continuing and have confirmed that it is safe to remove the GFCI or AFCI breaker, then start by tracing the white wires. One should be going to a bus bar in the breaker box and the other should be exiting the box with the black wire. Disconnect the one wire from the bus bar, and connect the other one to the bus bar in its place.

Comment: If a dedicated laundry circuit I would change out in a heartbeat. Oregon allows equipment known to have problems with GFCI/AFCI'S to be powered by a standard inverse time breaker.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that code might require this to be an AFCI/GFCI breaker, so you might be violating code if you do this, fair warning.

With that said, the black wire is the hot wire, which should go to the new breaker.  The white wire is the neutral, which should go to your neutral bus.

Your question itself shows that you only have a passing familiarity with electrical work, which is a red flag.  If you want to do this yourself, be aware that you likely need to learn more about the basics of electricity before opening, and working with your electrical panel.

With that said, this isn't rocket surgery.  As long as you understand what you're doing, you don't have to be afraid of everything instantly killing yourself, or setting your house on fire.  Those are real, valid concerns that people have, but they can be easily addressed by the average person with a little education about basic practices.